# Simple conditional statement issue

Tags: php

I am trying to stop the codes execution if the conditoin is met. I have

```
if(isset($fileName)){
    echo 'no more time!'
    //I want my script stops right here and don't excute the codes below...
}


//lots of codes.....
//lots of codes.....
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: this is the third time today i've seen the statement isset($variable).  the only reason you would use this is if you had register globals turned on... its deprecated you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can simply use:

```
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

`exit()` outputs a message and terminate the current script.

```
if(isset($fileName))
{
    echo 'no more time!';
    exit();
}
```

**[PHP Docs: exit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)**

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this function:

```
die();
```